# PHP - Replace A Set of Specific Characters and Then the Next 3 Characters After

Tags: php, string, image, wordpress

I'm moving the Featured Image Metabox in WordPress from the Side over to the Normal position. It now takes up a much wider portion of the screen than by default. The image that is placed in that metabox though is fixed at a certain height and width. I'm trying to remove that hardcoded height and width. I've got a string:

```
<img src="http://www.IMAGEFOLDERURL/imageone-300x225.jpg">
```

I need to remove the -300x225. However, the 225 is different for every image. So I need to remove "-300x***". * = anything. Is that possible with PHP?

EDIT: I'm not sure I'm being clear. The IMAGEFOLDERURL is filler, because the website could be anything. Also, I forgot to mention that the image url is part of a larger string. So after the:

```
<img src="http://www.IMAGEFOLDERURL/imageone-300x225.jpg">
```

There will be more. The entire string will be something like:

```
Variable length content here<img src="http://www.IMAGEFOLDERURL/imageone-300x225.jpg">Variable length content  after.
```

Comment: Those sizes are automatically generated by wordpress.  You can use http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail to get a specific size image.

Comment: Not when you are first selecting the image, before the post has been saved. I tried [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18337/how-to-get-featured-images-width-and-use-elsewhere-in-template), and I think you are talking about. It worked after the page had been saved, but during the initial selection of the image it returned nulls.

Comment: regexp - to the rescue!

Comment: If you're talking about the wordpress image selection dialog, there's actually a UI control there to select the correct image size.

Comment: No there isn't. You can select which one gets placed into new pages. You can't select which gets displayed in the actual metabox via a UI control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's what regexp is for

```
$string = '<img src="http://www.IMAGEFOLDERURL/imageone-300x225.jpg">';
$pattern = '/-300x[0-9]+/i';
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

this replaces anything that is '-300x[number]' with nothing

Answer (score 1):

More or less same as above, just different way of doing it.

If it will always be a fixed amount of characters ("-300x225.jpg" = 12) then you can use substr_ I think.

Eg.

```
$linkurl = 'http://www.IMAGEFOLDERURL/imageone-300x225.jpg';
$noextension = substr( $linkurl, 0, -12); // Removing the '-300x225.jpg'
$newlinkurl = $noextension . '.jpg'; // Adding .jpg
echo $newlinkurl;
```

Just make sure the extension is always the same and its always the same number of characters and you have it.

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/feg-77r

Comment: Only issue here is that it doesn't work with variable content after ".jpg"

Comment: Did you by any chance downvote the question? I just now noticed that it's got a -1 and I'm not sure why.